# How can I assign these objects before the unwrapping occurs?

Tags: ios, mobile, swift

So I was trying to make my own calculator for fun as I've moved from Android development to IOS and now I've tried to correct this error for 40 minutes and now I just give up, help me...

Okay so the error is pointing at the second @IBAction method which passes in two optionals to the method func add(param1, param2, param3). So first I thought that viewWillAppear is initiated after the connection is made with the UIElements. But this means I have to be able to access some method that is overridable and is initiated before the connection is made with the UIElements.

Is that a good way of doing this? Another solution would be to test the optionals before using them, but I know that you can skip this method if you are certain that your optionals do not contain a nil value.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //The memory that will be reserved for computation
    var memoryValue1: Double!, memoryValue2: Double!, memoryValue3: Double!, memoryValue4: Double!

    var firstAttempt: Bool!

    //UIElemet Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var outPutText: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        memoryValue1 = 0.0
        firstAttempt = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func add(value: Double, attempt: Bool, memory: Double){
        if attempt {
            self.firstAttempt = false
            self.memoryValue1 = value
            self.outPutText.text = String(value)
        } else {
            var newValue: Double = memory
            newValue = newValue + value
            self.outPutText.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pressedC(sender: AnyObject) {
        outPutText.text = "0.0"
    }
    @IBAction func pressed1(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(1.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed2(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(2.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed3(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(3.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed4(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(4.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed5(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(5.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed6(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(6.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed7(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(7, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed8(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(8.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed9(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(9.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
    @IBAction func pressed0(sender: AnyObject) {
        add(0.0, attempt: self.firstAttempt, memory: self.memoryValue1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var memoryValue1: Double!` is not a reference type like it is in Java. 
If you try to access it when it's nil (null) your app will crash. Access includes code like `self.memoryValue1` when the method in question attempts to pass the value contained in memoryValue1 to the add method.

Your learning process will be added greatly if you get out of the habit of putting a `!` at the end of all your property declarations. Go ahead and give such properties a value or use `?` instead.

You can assign by simply:

```
var memoryValue1: Double = 0.0
```